# Having an animated background in iOS app

Tags: ios, animation

Right now I have a UIImageView of a tree, with various UI elements placed on top of it.  I find this kind of borring to look at.  What I would like to do is to have my tree blowing in the wind.

My plan is to create my animation in Blender, and then export it as a video, and use this video in place of my background UIImageView.

A)  Is it possible to use a video in such a way?

B)  What type of view will I need?

C)  Is it possible to loop the video?

---

As I haven't started making the animation yet, I am flexible and would be open to other suggestions to acheive the same effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Place MoviePlayer at the bottom as a backgrond and play video. Jst try it and you will see result

Answer (score 1):

This is one way, which have a lot of images and passing these images to the UIImageView.

You have many images and save these images in an array.

```
backgroundImageView.animationImages = imagesArray;//pass in the array
backgroundImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
backgroundImageView.animationDuration = duration;//set some time.
[backgroundImageView startAnimating];
```

Hope this helps.. Just a suggestion

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I will need to evaluate how many different images I would need for a smooth animation.  If its not too many than this would take a lot less time than making an animation in blender